# Automatic start/uninstall of an app

Tags: android

I am trying to do something similar to the "SpeechSynthesis Data" app in the market. After installation it automagically starts itself, downloads the speech data to the sdcard, then uninstalls itself.

Does anyone know how you can have an app automatically start after installation? I can't find any info on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not automatically starting after installation. The TTS engine in Android is watching for the installation of the data app, and the TTS engine is the one that triggers the data app to run and download, and the TTS engine is the one uninstalling the application.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It does indeed seem to be impossible to automatically start the app after installation.

Comment: @CommonsWare: is it possible to uninstall apps from inside the app

Comment: @Ankit: No. At most, you can *request* to uninstall an app, but the user has to complete the process.